# Can leased out nxt coins still be used or do you have to wait for it to expire?

Tags: nxt, forging

When leasing out your nxt balance to another account, can you still use those coins in your main account? Or do you have to wait for it to expire before you can use it again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://nxtwiki.org/wiki/Account_Leasing:

> *Your balance never leaves your account*
>
> - Your funds are still on your account after you lease them. They are    still available for use: you can spend them, receive more etc. The only thing given is your forging power, by consequence while your balance is leased, you will not be able to forge on your own.

Your can spend your coins, but when you do your leased forging power will diminish.